# Python Searching text files in directory with subdirectories

Tags: python

I am trying to create a small project for my self and I am stuck.
I have a folder with subfolders and each subfolder is holding a text file named  *QWR.txt*. So I want to read all the files and store the text from files in one file.

This is my code:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.iglob('files/**/QWR.txt', recursive=True):
   with open(filename, 'r') as file:
      s = file.read()
   with open('output.txt', "wb") as file:
      file.write(s)
```

At the start it works but after 20+ files it get stuck and gives me an error:

```
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 1396: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: `with open(filename, 'rb') as file:`: problem gone. note that your code cannot work in python 3 because `s` is a string and the output file expects bytes.

Comment: But when i write to file it only writes 2 lines and i get "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: it means that it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your indentation is wrong. Well, there are 2 issues:

- you should use the binary mode to read & write to your file. You will avoid all python 2/3 compat. issues, CR add/removal and encoding errors
- open the output *before* the loop, or only the last file will be written into it (or use append mode)

like this:

```
import glob
with open('output.txt', "wb") as file:
   for filename in glob.iglob('files/**/QWR.txt', recursive=True):
      with open(filename, 'rb') as fr:
         fw.write(fr.read())
```

if the input files are huge and you cannot afford the memory by reading them globally, a good alternative to `fw.write(fr.read())` is:

```
shutil.copyfileobj(fr,fw)
```